# Problemas com arrays em Javascript

Tags: javascript, array

Bom, estou tendo alguns problemas com o seguinte trecho de código:

```
alert(lineOut[i].trim() + " - - " + lineOut[i + 1].trim());
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined(…)

O array `lineOut` é um array preenchido dinamicamente, que no momento da execução do trecho acima conta com os seguintes valores:

```
lineOut = ["6", "Comentario"];
```

Alguém pode me dar uma luz do porquê deste problema estar acontecendo?

Comment: Quanto vale `i` no momento da execução?

Comment: Esse código está a correr dentro de um ciclo `for`? vejo um risco de `i + 1` ser maior que o index do ultimo elemento da array e dar `undefined` por causa disso. Como o @Emoon perguntou, qual é o valor de `i` e qual é o valor de `lineOut.length` quando esse erro ocorre?

Comment: @Emoon `for(var i = 0; i<lineOut.length; i++)` esse é o cabeçalho do meu loop.

Comment: @Sergio `i = 0` e `lineOut.length = 2`. Mas provavelmente eu estou estourando o índice do array mesmo. Vou desenvolver uma outra lógica pra resolver esse problema. Muito obrigado pelo comentário.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu código deve ser parecido com isso:

```
var total = lineOut.length;
for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
    alert(lineOut[i].trim() + " - - " + lineOut[i + 1].trim());
}
```

O problema é que na última iteração, o `i` vale `(total - 1)` e o array `lineOut` vai de `lineOut[0], lineOut[1], ..., lineOut[total - 1]`. Você está tentando pegar `lineOut[i + 1]`, que é igual a `lineOut[(total - 1) + 1]`, ou seja, `lineOut[total]`, que está fora dos limites (só vai até `lineOut[total - 1]`).

Quando você tenta acessar algo fora dos limites de um array, o JS retorna `undefined`.

Comment: @Michele Akemi realmente é isso mesmo, vou adicionar uma condição pro `undefined`. Obrigado.